# What is a correct way to substring a string with NSRegularExpression results?

Tags: swift

I'm having a problem with this function:

```
    private func regexFirstGroup(in intext: String, pattern: String) -> String? {
    do {
        let nsrange = NSRange(intext.startIndex..<intext.endIndex, in: intext)
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [NSRegularExpression.Options.dotMatchesLineSeparators])
        if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: intext, options: [], range: nsrange) {
            guard let mrange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in:intext) else {
                return nil
            }
            return intext.substring(with: mrange)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Pattern \(pattern) compiled with error: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
    return nil
}
```

line with:

```
return intext.substring(with: mrange)
```

gives an deprecated warning:
'substring(with:)' is deprecated: Please use String slicing subscript.

and when I switch it to expected swift5 way:

```
return intext[mrange]
```

than it gives an error:
Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent

This is strange, because subscripting should work with String.Index types, and inspecting mrange constant in quick help shows:

```
Declaration
let mrange: Range<String.Index>
```

I'm not using import Foundation atm.

Comment: type(of: intext[mrange]) is Substring, and you are trying to return String?. 
Just wrap substring into String: 
`return String(intext[mrange])`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately "subscript(_:)' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent" is a very misleading compiler error. I thought that Substring is a subclass of String, and hence automatically casts to String. Double lesson here today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [subscript(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2943910-subscript)

```
return String(intext[mrange])
```

Comment: Thanks, accepted answer. Strangely complier error: "subscript(_:)' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent" doesn't help to find the problem and I could not google it out. Hope it helps someone in future.